# Add wave-files from genymotion-device to my computer

Tags: android, device, wav, genymotion

I created wave files on my virtual device. (genymotion)
Now I want them to add to my computer, how can I do this?

Comment: I adopted [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card/25159688#25159688)
Worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on many ways.

For example, ADB allows you to download a file from an Android device:

```
adb pull path/to/your/wav/source/file your/computer/target/folder/
```

Or you can use a shared folder as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card/18532431#18532431).

You will just need to copy your wave file into the device's shared folder and it will be automatically copied to you computer's target folder.