# How to get file from genymotion device

Tags: macos, genymotion

I am using osx-mavericks. I have a file in a genymotion Galaxy S4, in the download folder. I want to copy the file to my mac's desktop folder. The file is `.zip`. Is that possible?

I already tried [Accessing files from genymotion sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card) but it refuse to create the folder, complaining that my vm is in saved state and therefore cannot created shared folder

Comment: I have presently managed to create the shared folder. Where in the device would I find the folder? It is not under FileManager

Comment: This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card/25159688#25159688) may help you.

worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with help of Android Device monitor.
If you use Android Studio just open it from "Tools > Android > Device Monitor" then you will see connected devices and file explorer for the device.