# View Database of Genymotion Emulator in DDMS

Tags: android, genymotion

I have been trying to get a way to look at the database of my app on Genymotion in SQLite Manager plugin installed on Eclipse but no luck.

Was able to look at it using SQLite Manager app. But it would be handy if it is shown on DDMS perspective.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

i am also use genymotion emulator i am use my app DB like this

sqlite DB manager for emulator

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/irquka2js5svkfr/SQLite%20Editor%20Pro-com.htsoft.sqleditor-30-v3.0.0.apk

and if i want to move my db to PC  than share folder to your PC for that follow [this ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card/18532431#18532431)  and install [ROOT EXPLORER](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree&hl=en)