# How to remove Google Play Services from GenyMotion?

Tags: android, genymotion

I installed Google Play Services in GenyMotion(latest version including Virtual Box) referring [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su).

Now I want to remove Google Play Services and make GenyMotion back to its previous state. How can I do it ? (I use a Windows 8 system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the gapps zip into Genymotion writes many files into the system partition of the virtual machine. If you want to see a list, take a look at the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the zip file.

Installing a sideloaded zip like this is not really reversible unless you manually remove things and put back the originals of overwritten files.  In other words, it will be much easier for you to backup whatever you need from the device, delete it, and create a new one.

Comment: How to backup, delete and create a new one ?

Comment: Backup: it depends what you want to save. If it's just stuff on the /sdcard, there are some different ways suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card.  Delete: when the device is off, click the trash can icon in the Genymotion launcher, next to the device you want to delete. Create: click the +/Add icon in the top bar of the Genymotion launcher.

Comment: I don't want to backup anything from the /sdcard. I just want the GenyMotion as it was when it was installed first. How to do it ?

Comment: If you are a free user, then the only way to do it is delete the device (with the trash can button) and create a new one (with the + button). If you have a paid license, then you can click the reset button (circular arrow icon) next the device that you'd like to restore to its original state.

Comment: Paul gave a good answer but you can eventually also recreate a new device based on the same template than your device. Or before doing things like overriding your ROM, you should simply clone your device.