# How can I transfer files from my PC to Geynmotion Emulator Phone

Tags: android, file, genymotion, transfer

I want to show a picture to a friend via whatsapp and it does not work. I have the following problem, that I simply drag and drop pictures from my pc to the Genymotion emulator and it transfers it successfully but stil I cannot access it from my phone, it won't show in galeries or in the download section. I even used the option the root access a shared folder but i cannot copy the picture from this folder and paste it into the galery folder so i can access it in the whatsapp conversation menue. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do Drag and Drop.

### Close and reopen your device

#### Then only it will show the updated images to device.

You can install applications from the command prompt as usual, but you can also use a simple drag and drop! You can also import any file you need into your virtual device with a drag and drop.

[image]

For more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27447330/1761003)