# How to create SD card to use in Android Studio's emulator?

Tags: java, android, genymotion

I need to download mp3 files to an SD card in Android Studio and then read them, firstly, how can I create an SD card for my emulator? Secondly, how can I add files to it? I'm a beginner so a step by step explanation would be welcome.

Comment: follow this link https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/create-and-use-emulated-sd-card/

Comment: I managed to create the SDCard but how can I use it now? The tutorial is for Eclipse and I'm using Android Studio

Answer (score 12):

Android Studio 3.1.1

1.Create a emulator : **Tools > AVD Manager** , And run it

2.Open file system explorer **:View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer**

3.In **Device File Explorer** : Click right button , u will see **Upload** and **Save as**

Step1:

[image]

Step2:

[image]
Step3:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use the mksdcard tool to create a FAT32 disk image that you can load into emulators running different Android Virtual Devices (AVDs) to simulate the presence of the same SD card in multiple devices. If you do not need a disk image that can be shared among multiple virtual devices, you do not need to use the mksdcard command. By default the emulator uses the default image that is generated by and stored with the active AVD instead.

Example
Create the `mySdCardFile.img` disk image:

```
mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M mySdCardFile.img
```

Start two emulators with different AVDs.
 Use the `-sdcard` flag to specify the name and path of the disk image you created.

```
emulator -avd Pixel_API_25 -sdcard mySdCardFile.img
emulator -avd NEXUS_6_API_25 -sdcard mySdCardFile.img
```

Reference :

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/mksdcard.html

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help, as I said I'm a beginner and I need further explanation on how to do what you just said

Answer (score 3):

first take your Android "Virtual Device Manager"(AVD Manager on the top with a phone icon) and click on the "pencil icon"(edit) for editing your emulator then click "Show Advanced Settings option" there you can see a radio button for SD Card select " External file" insted of Studio-managed and provide your path and click on finish.

(AVD Manager>edit(pencil icon)>Show Advanced Settings option>External file)

Comment: how can i push files to it now?

Comment: just drag and drop your file into the emulator

Comment: thanks for the help, made really good progress, any tips on how to get the path of the file now to use it in my application (mp3 player)?

Comment: if you find my answer helpful plz accept my answer @joaolell

Comment: Keep in mind you can only edit this if you cloned a device. https://superuser.com/questions/1431473/cant-add-external-file-as-sd-card-in-avd-emulator/1433069

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I needed a lot of space for saving images in the emulator. My solution was creating an image sdcard and attach it to emulator. I followed these steps:

1 ) Create an image of external sdcard:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/mksdcard -l mySdCard 20G path/mySdCard.img
```

2 ) Create an emulator with the external sdcard:

```
~/Libarary/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n EMULATOR_NAME -k “system-images;android-24;default;x86” -f -c path/mySdCard.img
```

3 ) I searched for the external storage path with adb shell because the path to push the files is not very intuitive.

```
My sdcard path is in storage/15F5-0C07/
```

4 ) Push the files into external storage path

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb push localPath  /storage/15F5-0C07
```

I wrote all of the steps because I searched a lot for pushing the files into external storage and not into internal storage

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps to create an external sdcard Image

Step 1:
      Navigate to your android sdk directory and to the following directory inside it.

> /{your_androidSdk_location}/Android/sdk/emulator

Step 2:
      Ensure that there is a executable file named **mksdcard**.

Step 3:
Create another directory to store the image file(.img file) that is going to be created in the next step. Lets call this directory as **image_dir**

Step4: Execute the following command

```
./mksdcard -l mylabel 1024M image_dir/sdcard.img
```

Now the .img file would have been created.

Step 5: Now edit your emulator in the AVD manager and select **Advanced Settings** , under the **Memory and Storage** section select external file radio button for **Sd Card** and choose the .img file that was created in step 4.

Happy emulated Storage

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use Genymotion for this its working awesome.

> Here is the brief:
>
> Go to your VirtualBox VM setting / Shared folder tab.
>
> Add a shared folder with the folder you want to share, and check the
>   "auto mount" option.
>
> Start your VM as usual from the Genymotion software.
>
> Your shared folder is available in the /mnt/shared directory (multiple
>   shared folders are supported)

[Accessing files from Genymotion sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card)

Comment: Sounds like an Ad: contains Genymotion three time, without any hindsight about how it works, what are alternatives way (e.g., load an apk, ...) to access shared folders, how much it costs, ...